# CLoudflare page rules: force SSL except specified URL pattern?

Tags: web, https, redirect, cloudflare

Is it possible to force SSL with Cloudflare except specified URL pattern? for example: `example.com/*` forced to use SSL, but `example.com/iframe` use HTTP only, not HTTPS.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using `Automatic HTTPS Rewrites` within CloudFlare's Crypto section, yes. Create a Page Rule for `example.com/iframe*` where `Automatic HTTPS Rewrites` is off. See attached image for the Page Rule setting:

[image]

But you might be redirecting with Microsoft IIS or Apache. In that case, you must make the distinction there.

Comment: Apologies for downvoting, I had some conflicting settings and when I removed them, it did work.  Thank you for your answer.  Unfortunately I can't seem to undo my downvote unless the answer is edited.  I'd be happy to remove my downvote if you want to make a minor edit to I can do so.

Comment: I was able to change my downvote to an upvote.  Righting some wrongs here :)

Comment: Very smart workaround!